# How to change solana initial supply in own custom cluster?

Tags: blockchain, solana, genesis, solana-cli

The problem I'm working on is my team wants me to setup my own cluster with an initial supply of 400M sol. I have gone through the genesis module and found some genesis accounts. I couldnt really find the total supply or mint_lamports anywhere except for it being in test-validator module. could anyone please help me out with this? thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track!  The genesis accounts will contain all of the SOL in the network as defined at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3c7022014211b26bca03793f198c31e986e4dbd1/genesis/src/genesis_accounts.rs#L230

Specifically, the 500m SOL is defined here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3c7022014211b26bca03793f198c31e986e4dbd1/genesis/src/genesis_accounts.rs#L259

In your case, you'll want to change up the owners of the stake accounts to keys that you own, or remove them entirely.  It's up to you how to distribute the genesis tokens.