# Stake Granularity in solana

Tags: solana, genesis, solana-cli

Hello Can anyone please explain why is stake granularity important in solana? and also if I change all the stakers to one single address my total supply varies significantly,any explanation for this?

```
pub const CREATOR_STAKER_INFOS: &[StakerInfo] = &[
    StakerInfo {
        name: "impossible pizza",
        staker: "uE3TVEffRp69mrgknYr71M18GDqL7GxCNGYYRjb3oUt",
        lamports: 100_000_000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        withdrawer: Some("59SLqk4ete5QttM1WmjfMA7uNJnJVFLQqXJSy9rvuj7c"),
    },
];

pub const SERVICE_STAKER_INFOS: &[StakerInfo] = &[
    StakerInfo {
        name: "wretched texture",
        staker: "uE3TVEffRp69mrgknYr71M18GDqL7GxCNGYYRjb3oUt",
        lamports: 5_000_000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        withdrawer: Some("HWzeqw1Yk5uiLgT2uGUim5ocFJNCwYUFbeCtDVpx9yUb"),
    },
    
];

pub const FOUNDATION_STAKER_INFOS: &[StakerInfo] = &[
    StakerInfo {
        name: "lyrical supermarket",
        staker: "uE3TVEffRp69mrgknYr71M18GDqL7GxCNGYYRjb3oUt",
        lamports: 5_000_000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        withdrawer: Some("C7WS9ic7KN9XNcLsNoMvzTvbzURM3rFGDEQN7qJMWNLn"),
    },
    
];

pub const GRANTS_STAKER_INFOS: &[StakerInfo] = &[
    StakerInfo {
        name: "rightful agreement",
        staker: "uE3TVEffRp69mrgknYr71M18GDqL7GxCNGYYRjb3oUt",
        lamports: 5_000_000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        withdrawer: Some("EDwSQShtUWQtmFfN9SpUUd6hgonL7tRdxngAsNKv9Pe6"),
    },
    
];

pub const COMMUNITY_STAKER_INFOS: &[StakerInfo] = &[
    StakerInfo {
        name: "shrill charity",
        staker: "uE3TVEffRp69mrgknYr71M18GDqL7GxCNGYYRjb3oUt",
        lamports: 5_000_000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        withdrawer: Some("8CUUMKYNGxdgYio5CLHRHyzMEhhVRMcqefgE6dLqnVRK"),
    },
    
];
```

Comment: There's nothing specific to Solana here, it's just spreading the initial supply of SOL to multiple holders.  Regarding the capitalization, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221535/how-to-change-solana-initial-supply-in-own-custom-cluster/ answer the question?

Comment: Thank you, Jon. But I didnt get how the supply is calculated if I change the unlocks in add_genesis_accounts() in genesis/genesis_accounts.rs the total supply is not 500M even though i didnt chnage the number.I get the non circulating supply but the total supply doesnt make sense.  Total: 2704999904.444771 SOL
Circulating: 55000505.48236209 SOL
Non-Circulating: 2649999398.962409 SOL

Comment: Since your total amount is so much larger than 500 million SOL, https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3c7022014211b26bca03793f198c31e986e4dbd1/genesis/src/genesis_accounts.rs#L259 just evaluates to 0, so only the SOL defined in your accounts will be included

Comment: oh thank you, so much jon, Could you please direct me to the file where the above mentioned logic is? because im trying to gather all the pieces which influence total supply like inflation, rewards, slashing , disinflation and burn

Comment: The line linked from genesis_accounts.rs in my reply is where the logic lives

Comment: Thank you Jon, can we connect further to discuss more about solana?